# Array of uniq_ptr pointer pointing to list of uniq_ptr

Tags: c++, arrays, unique-ptr

searched all over, Couldn't find answer I'm looking for w.r.t. unique_ptr. It's a problem I came across, couldn't solve it with unique_ptr, but I could do with traditional way.

I'm stuck with having array of pointers to abstract_base_class pointing to inherited class

Sorry posting whole code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

// Base is an abstract base class.
class Base {
private:
    string myName;   // Name of this person
public:
    Base(string name) : myName(name) {}
    // A pure virtual function with a function body
    virtual void hello() const  {
        cout << "Hello, my name is " << myName
            << ". ";
    }
};

class ServiceAgent : public Base {
public:
    ServiceAgent(string name) : Base(name) {}
    void hello() const {
        Base::hello();
        cout << "I'm a customer service representative. How may I help you?"
            << endl;
        cout << "-----\n";
    }
};

class Student : public Base {
public:
    enum category { FRESHMAN, SOPHOMORE, JUNIOR, SENIOR };
    category personType;

    Student(string name, category pType) : Base(name) {
        personType = pType;
    }
    void hello() const {
        string tmp = enumToString(personType);
        Base::hello();
        cout << tmp << endl;
        cout << "-----\n";
    }
    string enumToString (category c) const
    {
        string s;
        switch (c) {
            case FRESHMAN:
                s = "I'm a Freshman";
                break;
            case SOPHOMORE:
                s = "I'm a Sophomore";
                break;
            case JUNIOR:
                s = "I'm a Junior";
                break;
            case SENIOR:
                s = "I'm a Senior";
                break;
            default:
                s = "none";
                break;
            }
        return s;
    }
};

class CSStudent : public Student {
public:
    CSStudent(string name, Student::category type) : Student(name, type) {}
    void hello() const {
        Base::hello();
        cout << "I'm a computer science major.\n";
        cout << "-----\n";
    }
};

class BUSStudent : public Student {
public :
    BUSStudent(string name, Student::category type) : Student(name, type) {}
    void hello() {
        Base::hello();
        cout << "I'm a business major.\n";
        cout << "-----\n";
    }
};

int main() {

    ServiceAgent    *agentJack = new ServiceAgent("Jacqueline");
    Student        *studentJack = new Student("Jackson", Student::FRESHMAN);
    CSStudent              *studentCSS = new CSStudent("Jack", Student::SOPHOMORE);
    BUSStudent            *studentBus1 = new BUSStudent("Jacky", Student::JUNIOR);
    BUSStudent            *studentBus2 = new BUSStudent("Joyce", Student::SENIOR);

    Base *arr[] = { agentJack, studentJack, studentCSS, studentBus1, studentBus2};

    for  (Base  *var : arr)
    {
       var->hello();
    }



    unique_ptr<ServiceAgent> u_agentJack(new ServiceAgent("Jacqueline"));
    unique_ptr<Student> u_studentJack(new Student("Jackson", Student::FRESHMAN));
    unique_ptr<CSStudent>       u_studentCSS(new CSStudent("Jack", Student::SOPHOMORE));
    unique_ptr<BUSStudent>     u_studentBus1(new BUSStudent("Jacky", Student::JUNIOR));
    unique_ptr<BUSStudent>     u_studentBus2(new BUSStudent("Joyce", Student::SENIOR));


      //unique_ptr<Base*> ptr ; //(new Base*);//{ u_agentJack, u_studentJack, u_studentCSS, u_studentBus1, u_studentBus2 };
      //ptr = static_cast<unique_ptr<Base*>>u_agentJack;

    return 0;
}
```

I tried these, doesn't work.

```
  unique_ptr<Base*> ptr (new (Base*[5] { u_agentJack, u_studentJack, u_studentCSS, u_studentBus1, u_studentBus2 });
```

tried with single entry

```
  //ptr = static_cast<unique_ptr<Base*>>u_agentJack;
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named [What to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What not to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read the [StackOverflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Compilable, Complete, and Verifiable Examples with a main() function](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `std::unique_ptr<Base*>` to `std::unique_ptr<Base>`, and add a virtual destructor to `Base`. Then you can declare an array of `unique_ptr<Base>` objects the same way you declare an array of `Base*` pointers, and `std::move()` your existing `std::unique_ptr` objects into the array.

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

// Base is an abstract base class.
class Base {
private:
    string myName;   // Name of this person
public:
    Base(string name) : myName(name) {}
    virtual ~Base() {}

    // A pure virtual function with a function body
    virtual void hello() const  {
        cout << "Hello, my name is " << myName << ".";
    }
};

class ServiceAgent : public Base {
public:
    ServiceAgent(string name) : Base(name) {}

    void hello() const override {
        Base::hello();
        cout << " I'm a customer service representative. How may I help you?" << endl;
    }
};

class Student : public Base {
public:
    enum category { FRESHMAN, SOPHOMORE, JUNIOR, SENIOR };
    category personType;

    Student(string name, category pType) : Base(name), personType(pType) {}

    void hello() const override {
        Base::hello();
        cout << " " << enumToString(personType) << endl;
    }

    string enumToString (category c) const
    {
        switch (c) {
            case FRESHMAN:
                return "I'm a Freshman";
            case SOPHOMORE:
                return "I'm a Sophomore";
            case JUNIOR:
                return "I'm a Junior";
            case SENIOR:
                return "I'm a Senior";
        }
        return "";
    }
};

class CSStudent : public Student {
public:
    CSStudent(string name, Student::category type) : Student(name, type) {}

    void hello() const override {
        Student::hello();
        cout << "I'm a computer science major." << endl;
    }
};

class BUSStudent : public Student {
public :
    BUSStudent(string name, Student::category type) : Student(name, type) {}

    void hello() const override {
        Student::hello();
        cout << "I'm a business major." << endl;
    }
};

int main() {

    std::unique_ptr<ServiceAgent> agentJack(new ServiceAgent("Jacqueline"));
    std::unique_ptr<Student> studentJack(new Student("Jackson", Student::FRESHMAN));
    std::unique_ptr<CSStudent> studentCSS(new CSStudent("Jack", Student::SOPHOMORE));
    std::unique_ptr<BUSStudent> studentBus1(new BUSStudent("Jacky", Student::JUNIOR));
    std::unique_ptr<BUSStudent> studentBus2(new BUSStudent("Joyce", Student::SENIOR));

    std::unique_ptr<Base> arr[] = { std::move(agentJack), std::move(studentJack), std::move(studentCSS), std::move(studentBus1), std::move(studentBus2) };

    for (auto &var : arr)
    {
        var->hello();
        cout << "-----" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/hI4XQs)

Comment: True, though `std::make_unique()` was not in C++11 with `std::unique_ptr`, it was added later in C++14

Comment: I don't see C++11 tag or mention of it by OP, So I would be free to use C++14 :-)

Comment: Hi Remy and all, Thanks for immediate answer, helped a lot, stackoverflow.com has been wonderful to me, so helpful people, Appreciate members support, a priceless help.

Comment: Hi All, How do I add 'individual unique_ptr' into an array?, something like this

std::unique_ptr<Base> arr[] = { agentJack, studentJack, studentCSS, studentBus1, studentBus2 };
I tried, it doesn't work. Something Similar to earlier old code that works
//old style
Base *arr[] = { agentJack, studentJack, studentCSS, studentBus1, studentBus2};

Comment: @NalanP did you not read the code I posted in my answer? It shows you exactly how to create an array of `unique_ptr` objects from individual `unique_ptr` variables: `std::unique_ptr<Base> arr[] = { std::move(agentJack), std::move(studentJack), std::move(studentCSS), std::move(studentBus1), std::move(studentBus2) };` You are just missing the `std::move()` calls, since only 1 `unique_ptr` instance at a time can refer to any given allocated object.

Comment: @Remy, Thanks for response, I was wondering if we could do it without std::move,  <br>
like arr[] = { agentJack, studentJack ...}; sounds like language doesn't allow. <br>
PS: Sorry I'm sort of new programmer, doing a crash course leads tons of confusion.

Comment: @NalanP "*I was wondering if we could do it without std::move*" - not when using separate `std::unique_ptr` variables, because `std::unique_ptr` does not support being copied, only moved, that is how it maintains unique ownership of the held pointer. The alternative is to construct the objects directly in the array, eg: `std::unique_ptr<Base> arr[] = { std::unique_ptr<Base>(new ServiceAgent("Jacqueline")), ...};` or `std::unique_ptr<Base> arr[] = { std::make_unique<ServiceAgent>("Jacqueline"), ...};` If you don't like this, use `std::shared_ptr` instead, which supports being copied